# Storing Fourier Magnitude in an image

Tags: opencv

I am trying a DFT program   . In it I am finding the Frequency magnitude/spectrum for each coefficient.
I have created an image, img, which is a 64 * 64 , 8 bit unsigned image with one channel.

```
Mat im2(64, 64, CV_8UC1);
```

Then we find the frequency spectrum which gives a very large value which is assigned to t.

```
double t = round(sqrt(pow(sum1, 2) + pow(sum2, 2)));
```

The problem lies here: How can I assign such a large value to a uchar image. What to do and how to do?

```
im2.at<uchar>(u, v) = t;
```

Comment: why use a uchar Mat to store this ?

Comment: What should I use then. Please guide.

Comment: Mat im2(64, 64, CV_64FC1);  ... im2.at<double>(u, v) = t;

Comment: Yes its working but there is one more problem.I know Fourier transformed image is total black with one white spot that indicate DC component but as we can see from above code magnitude is on higher side, so should not it be total white?

Comment: ...total black - means in imshow() ? you could try to print it to console: `cerr << im2 << endl;` and see, what's your actual range

Comment: Am I right? If not please guide.